Semi dried vs dried tomatoes
I imagine Semi dried tomatoes are basically partially rather than fully dried and as such they retain more of the original tomato flavour.
What other pros and cons do semi dried tomatoes have and when might you use them? As they contain more water I’d imagine they have a reduced shelf life as compared to dried, how long might the semi dried last for?
Thanks

First it would depend what the "semi-dried" tomatoes actually are. Not very well dried tomatoes - seems very likely to spoil rapidly. Some product with various preservatives and water replacers - not really a dried tomato at all, but might have some shelf life - consult the package. Fully dried tomatoes keep for years without spoilage if kept dry; if not dried at excessive temperatures they retain most of the original flavor, not that you'll ever confuse dried for fresh.
